# Size of Popup View

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, popup

I have a popup view, in that there is a scroll view and other views like some labels, buttons. But the height of popup view doesn't increase or decreases automatically based on it's subviews. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language or motive you're referring to, but if in the ordinance of Web Development, try this out:

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Responsive Popup</h1>
    <p>Click on the button below to view the responsive popup.</p>
    <button data-js="open">Open popup</button>
</div>

<div class="popup">
    <h2>This is my popup</h2>
    <button name="close">Close popup</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass";

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 240px;
    text-align: center;

    .container {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 5px solid #9AD3DE;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}

h1, p, h2, button {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

p {
    color: #666666;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

button {
    background: #89BDD3;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &:hover {
        background: lighten(#89BDD3, 10%);
    }
}

.popup {
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index: 5000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    > div {
        border-radius: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(#000000, 0.3);
        padding: 30px 15px;
        /* Width of popup can be changed */
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 600px;
        z-index: 5001;
        @include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
        left: 50%;
       top: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 5px solid #9AD3DE;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
function popupOpenClose(popup) {

    /* Add div inside popup for layout if one doesn't exist */
    if ($(".wrapper").length == 0){
        $(popup).wrapInner("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
    }

    /* Open popup */
    $(popup).show();

    /* Close popup if user clicks on background */
    $(popup).click(function(e) {
        if ( e.target == this ) {
            if ($(popup).is(':visible')) {
                $(popup).hide();
            }
        }
    });

    /* Close popup and remove errors if user clicks on cancel or close buttons */
    $(popup).find("button[name=close]").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".formElementError").is(':visible')) {
            $(".formElementError").remove();
        }
        $(popup).hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-js=open]").on("click", function() {
        popupOpenClose($(".popup"));
    });
});
```

Comment: That is what Im here for

Comment: @user2592356 you can check the tag below asking question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proportional height constraint with the superView like this

```
popupView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.heightAnchor,multiplier:0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your constraints correctly within the popup, 
the height of the popup will be determined by it’s content.

What you need to do (when setting up the constraints) is to make sure that the height for all the subviews of the popup is determined by their content (for labels and buttons you get it for free from iOS).
UIScrollView does not change it’s size based on it’s content, 
so you have to give it a height constraint.
You also need to have the vertical distances between the popup’s subviews setup.
Besides that, you need to have constraints for the popup’s view, locating it in it’s superview and **NOT** to have constraints 
that control it’s height.

That way , when the content of the labels and the buttons changes, their height will change and so will the height of the popup.

Another way of achieving your goal is to override the variable **intrinsicContentSize** of your popup 
(assuming your popup is a custom view).